# Fan problem in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, fan

I have a problem with my laptop fan. I update Nvidia drivers in ubuntu 19.10, When restarting the system, I can't log in to Ubuntu. I enter my password and then the screen froze. So, I boot ubuntu in recovery mode and uninstall Nvidia drivers with the terminal. when restarting the device, I was able to log in and the graphic drive has to Intel, But my laptop fan is always on at high speed. The fan is the normal speed in windows (my laptop has dual boot).

I try again to install Nvidia, when installing complete and restart the device, a black screen shows!

I think I said everything. How I can repair the fan and install Nvidia?

My laptop model is **Asus n552vw**.

Comment: What model Nvidia. What version drivers?

Comment: @heynnema I dont khow, sorry.

Comment: You probably have a NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX™ 960M. What was the name of the Nvidia driver you tried to install? Can you boot to Recovery Mode and uninstall whatever Nvidia you installed? Nvidia version 440.64 can be downloaded from https://www.geforce.com/drivers.